# When should I be using a php framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I am a newbie of PHP and just got informed that the developing process could be made much easier by using a PHP framework (e.g., Codeigniter, Cakephp...), but, do professional web developers use a framework in whatever PHP projects they come across, or just *sometimes*?

Comment: Some developers use, others don't.

Comment: And some even use it, but don't utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we do :)

http://framework.zend.com/

http://codeigniter.com/

http://nette.org/cs/

forexample :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, exus :)